# zend framework action name changes to 'id'

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I have a zend framework application with modules 'dashboard' and 'admin' of which 'dashboard' is the default one. When I try to access a different module, I am getting the request object like this

```
Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object
(
    [_paramSources:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => _GET
            [1] => _POST
        )

    [_requestUri:protected] => /admin/application/show/
    [_baseUrl:protected] => http://local.dashmonitor.us.com
    [_basePath:protected] => 
    [_pathInfo:protected] => /admin/application/show/
    [_params:protected] => Array
        (
            [module] => admin
            [controller] => application
            [action] => get
            [id] => show
        )

    [_rawBody:protected] => 
    [_aliases:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_dispatched:protected] => 1
    [_module:protected] => admin
    [_moduleKey:protected] => module
    [_controller:protected] => application
    [_controllerKey:protected] => controller
    [_action:protected] => get
    [_actionKey:protected] => action
)
```

My real action name is 'show' but it changes to 'get' here. Can anybody please help?

Comment: post your route setup, your defaults are likely incorrect or in the wrong order. Remember LIFO (Last In First OUT).

Comment: I had 2 lines of code in my bootstrap(written by earlier developers) which I commented right now                                  //$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($frontController); 
 //$frontController->getRouter()->addRoute('default', $restRoute);                                                         When I commented then, it started working!!! Thanks RockyFord. But I need to check whether it will affect in any other way